# How to get assocated model's attribute values in views ? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, controllers

I have three models...

***models/resident.rb***

```
class Resident < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hostel
  has_many :leaves,dependent: :delete_all
  has_one :user,dependent: :delete
end
```

***models/user.rb***

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resident
end
```

***models/leave.rb***

```
class Leave < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resident
end
```

Now when I am trying to access the value of leave's attribute in ***views/leave/show.html.erb***
I am getting this:

***app/views/leaves/show.html.erb***

```
<%= @leaves %>
```

out put In Browser :

```
#<Leave::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fde611850f0>
```

My leave controller looks like :
***leaves_controller.rb***

```
class LeavesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    if logged_in?
       @leave=Leave.new
    else
      flash[:info]="Please login to mark a leave"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
   def show
     @leaves= current_user.resident.leaves
   end

  def create
    @leave=current_user.resident.leaves.create(leave_params)
    if @leave.save
      flash[:info] = "Leave successfully marked"
      redirect_to new_leave_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Something wrong Happened try again"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  private
  def leave_params
    params.require(:leave).permit(:start_date,:end_date,:destination)
  end
end
```

Am I making correct leaves for resident and related user ***(create method)***?

Is show method correct ?

and How to assess the user's leaves attribute in ***show.html.erb*** of leaves views.

Comment: Do it like : `@leaves= current_user.resident.leaves.first` to get first object or loop through `@leaves= current_user.resident.leaves` in show.html to show all leaves. As `@leaves= current_user.resident.leaves` will return a collection not an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Resident has_many Leaves so current_resident.leaves returns an array of all the current_resident's leaves. You will need to loop through leaves to show individual attributes. Try

```
@leaves.first.attribute_name
```

in your view to get an idea of how the data is represented. To show all the leaves you'll need to use a loop in the view

```
@leaves.each do |leave|
  leave.inspect
end
```

Comment: Please would you accept the answer or vote it up if it helped as I am trying to build up my profile points.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing everything fine, and `show` method is fine, and the template shows exactly what is was told to show.

`@leaves` is a collection. You probably want to show it’s elements? This should lead to the proper solution:

```
<% @leaves.each do |l| %>
  <%= l.inspect %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: one more question about partials : I have a partial _usermenu.html.erb
and I want to show it except my home page. But My home page is dynamic  means changes with user. like If user is logged in then it will show his profile and if not then the main content of site. Now I want   _usermenu.html.erb to show in all except my main  content page or if the user is logged in .. I also have the function for identifying the logged in user.  Can i render that partial using that function? but exactly I dont know how to use it.. can u help !

Comment: Please post another question. This site has it’s own rules.